# non-static method openInputFile(String) cannot be referenced from a static contex java

Tags: java, static

Here is my code in question:

```
public File openInputFile(Scanner kb)
{
  if(kb == null)
  {   
     throw new RuntimeException("ERROR! Scanner Not Detected.");
  }
  System.out.print("Enter Name of File: ");
  String fn = kb.nextLine();
  File inf = FileUtil.openInputFile(fn); 
  return inf;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
FileUtil.java:33: error: non-static method openInputFile(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
      File inf = FileUtil.openInputFile(fn); 
                         ^
```

Nothing is static, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Can anyone help?

Comment: the way you used it tells the compiler it is static.

Comment: when the method is static you gonna use it like the name of the class.the name of method

Comment: Even it is not clear what you try to accomplish by your code.

Answer (score 0):

`File inf = FileUtil.openInputFile(fn);`
tells the compiler that `openInputFile(fn)` is static method of class `FileUtil` because you are trying to make a call to the method from the class name itself. This is why compiler said

`FileUtil.java:33: error: non-static method openInputFile(String) cannot be referenced from a static context`

So, all you need to do it is, make an object of file util and call the method from that object.

Comment: the op uses the openInputFile method inside the Method openInputFile

Comment: Param type differs. FileUtil method accept String whereas op's method has argument of type 'Scanner`

Answer (score 0):

`FileUtil` class has a method `openInputFile()` that seems to be non static, hence you have to call it by creating instance of `FileUtil`

```
FileUtil fileut= new FileUtil();
fileut.openInputFile();
```

Comment: the op uses the openInputFile method inside the Method openInputFile

Comment: Yes But those methods seem to be overridden, since they have different params

Comment: but it sounds confusing and does not express what programmer tries to accomplish here ?!!!!

Comment: Hmm exactly, but I think in any case this would work, even if the both the methods, `openInputFile(scanner)` and `openInputFile(String)` are part of the same class (overriden methods). Or the `openInputFile(scanner)` method is present in completely different class. But yes its really unclear what OP is trying to achieve

Comment: @KickButtowski It surely does looks confusing, but different issue. Seems more like design issue rather than compiler error.

Comment: @Mustafasabir good point. it seems the op overloded the openInputFile but it is very confusing again :)

Comment: @GauravGupta I am totally with you :)